# Mrs. Piggle-Wiggle Comic Book

Tags: comics, episode-identification

The *[Mrs. Piggle-Wiggle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mrs._Piggle-Wiggle)* series of books by Betty MacDonald featured an occasionally magical woman in a small neighborhood who cured the bad habits of children around her with a combination of psychology and magic cures sourced from her deceased pirate husband. I was extremely fond of the books as a child, checking them out many times from the library. At one point in primary school (maddeningly, I know whose house it was, but I went to school with him from kindergarten to high school, so it doesn't narrow it down much), probably around 1990ish one of my friends showed me a comic-book adaptation of the series. I don't recall many details, but I remember the tone being very different. Rather than parents seeking out Mrs. Piggle-Wiggle for cures to their children's bad habits, it had Mrs. Piggle-Wiggle asking the children for help, with them traveling to another world, I think. The image in my head of the book had one of the children (I think a dark-haired male?) stepping across the threshold of the door to the house built into the roof (the house being famously upside-down) and I think a later panel with him and some of the other children looking through the chest of cures for items to help them on their voyage. My memory of the art-style was more realistic, and done in something more like watercolors on a glossy page than standard comic book 4-color on pulp paper.

It is possible that my brain is recalling a copy of one of the books that presented the story with more illustration than the copies I grew up with, and my memories have been embellished over the years, but I could have sworn that it was a comic book adaptation with an expansion of the original stories, likely authorized by her daughter or her estate, since Betty MacDonald died in 1958.

Comment: https://whattoreadtoyourkids.com/2017/01/12/new-mrs-piggle-wiggle-series/ - They did a heavily illustrated reboot thing, apparently.

Comment: I've requested a copy, but the timeline doesn't fit. Those were published much later.

Comment: There where  two shortened stories with new illustrations made  in 1997 that were based on the "The Won't-Pick-Up-Toys Cure" and the "The Radish Cure" from the first book. The  illustrations, made by Bruce Whatley, match your description of "watercolors on a glossy page" but the particular images you mention are not there.. It is possible there are more books but i have not been able to find them. The story you describe sounds a bit like the "The Waddle-I-Doers" from Mrs. Piggle-Wiggle's Magic but that is just a guess.